# Printing A Pattern in C

Tags: c

I am a beginner in programming, I studied all about C, I started to solve problems from hackerrank.com,  there I faced a problem to print a pattern like given below
([the output of problem program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBaeT.png)):

```
4 4 4 4 4 4 4
4 3 3 3 3 3 4
4 3 2 2 2 3 4
4 3 2 1 2 3 4
4 3 2 2 2 3 4
4 3 3 3 3 3 4
4 4 4 4 4 4 4
```

the input will be an integer which will provide the data for the length of pattern square, here it is 4 in image,
I tried a lot to type a proper logic and I end up with this useless code bellow:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    
    int array[n- 1 + n][n - 1 + n];
    array[(n - 1 + n) / 2][(n - 1 + n) / 2] = 1;
    int f[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        f[i] = i;
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < n - 1 + n; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < n - 1 + n; j++) {
            array[j][i] = n - f[j];                    //top
            array[i][j] = n - f[j];                    //left
            array[(2 * n - 1 - 1) - i][j] = n - f[i];  //bottem
            array[j][(2 * n - 1 - 1) - i] = n - f[i];  //rigth
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < n - 1 + n; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < n - 1 + n; j++) {
            printf("%d ", array[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

my logic was to make all four borders correct in for loop which will end at center, but its not working, I want a new logic or to improve my logic, if you want to help me out then please give me the way to solve problem instead of giving me a direct code.

Comment: In your question, you wrote: "the input will be an integers which will decide to make pattern" -- Are you talking about one integer or several integers? And what exactly does this integer represent? The size of every dimension of the grid, so `7` in your example? Or the maximum distance from the center, so `3` in your example?

Comment: actually, the problem is If you input any number, program will give a square, where the length is 2n-1, n is input number, and the pattern will be just like I shown in image (depends on what your input is), i tried with array, but that's not working.

Comment: Take extra note of @ScottHunter 's comment, and try out a solution on pen/paper. Notice what the "coordinates" of each index is (with the center being `0,0`), and compare that to the value you're expecting to output. You might find there's a mathematical relationship between the largest coordinate number, and the number to be printed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is observable that the pattern consists of `n` stacked squares:

- Square `#0` is drawn with `n`s.
- Square `#1` is drawn with `n-1`s.
- ...
- Square `#n-1` is drawn with `1`s.

Implementing the above:

```
void draw_pattern(const size_t n)
{
    const size_t dim = 2*n-1;
    int array[dim][dim];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) { // Outer square #i
        // Row #0 of the outer square #i
        for (size_t j = i; j < dim-i; ++j)
            array[i][j] = n-i;
            
        // Row #n-1 of the outer square #i
        for (size_t j = i; j < dim-i; ++j)
            array[dim-i-1][j] = n-i;
        
        // Col #0 of the outer square #i
        for (size_t j = i; j < dim-i; ++j)
            array[j][i] = n-i;
        
        // Col #n-1 of the outer square #i
        for (size_t j = i; j < dim-i; ++j)
            array[j][dim-i-1] = n-i;
    }
    
    print_array(dim, array);
}
```

This is `print_array()`:

```
void print_array(const size_t dim, int array[dim][dim])
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < dim; ++i) {
        for(size_t j = 0; j < dim; ++j)
            printf("%d ", array[i][j]);
        
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
4 4 4 4 4 4 4
4 3 3 3 3 3 4
4 3 2 2 2 3 4
4 3 2 1 2 3 4
4 3 2 2 2 3 4
4 3 3 3 3 3 4
4 4 4 4 4 4 4
```

The worst case time complexity is O(n<sup>2</sup>).

Answer (score 1):

When you get a problem like this, try to dumb it down as much a possible. This square can be separated into 8 same, just rotated "slices" that look like:

```
4      | 4444 | 4444  |    4
43     |  333 | 333   |   34
432    |   22 | 22    |  234
4321   |    1 | 1     | 1234
```

... and the same for the bottom half, just flipped.

You can see this in the code bellow, to check what line is writing what part of the square, comment it and you will see what section shows zeroes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()  {

int n;
scanf("%d", &n);

int array[2 * n - 1][2 * n - 1];
for(int i = 0; i < 2 * n - 1; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 2 * n - 1; j++){
        array[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
int f[n];
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    f[i] = i;
}

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for(int j = i; j < n; j++)
    {
        array[i][j] = n - i;
        array[j][i] = n - i;//top left
        
        array[j][2*n - i - 2] = n - i;
        array[i][2*n - j - 2] = n - i;//bottom left
        
        array[2*n - j - 2][i] = n - i;
        array[2*n - i - 2][j] = n - i;//top right
        
        array[2*n - i - 2][2*n - j - 2] = n - i;
        array[2*n - j - 2][2*n - i - 2] = n - i;//bottom right
    }
}


for(int i = 0; i < n - 1 + n; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < n - 1 + n; j++)
    {
        printf("%d ", array[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

return 0;
}
```